# Code works when relevant part is commented (python 3.6,spyder IDE)

Tags: python

I was testing `torchvision` data-sets and I find out that after the first run if I comment the loading  part of the data-set from my code it run faster (`0.6654326915740967` seconds compare to `7.922324180603027` seconds). I think it does this because it need to reload the data-set, but where is the loaded data-set stored and why the code compile without it I don't know.

Why/How  does it work ? How can I achieve the same thing without manually commenting and uncommenting ?

code:

```
import torch 
import torchvision
from torchvision import transforms
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader

import time
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def ShowImage(imag):      
    temp=imag.view(3,96,96)
    temp=temp.cpu()
    temp =transforms.functional.to_pil_image(temp)
    plt.imshow(temp)
    plt.show()

path = '/home/Machine Learning/Datasets'  
start = time.time()

ToTensor = transforms.Compose([transforms.ToTensor()])
train_data= torchvision.datasets.STL10(path ,
                                       split='train'
                                     ,transform=ToTensor) 
test_data= torchvision.datasets.STL10(path ,
                                       split='test'
                                     ,transform=ToTensor) 
dataloader_train = DataLoader(train_data,batch_size=1,shuffle=True)
for i,batch in enumerate(dataloader_train):
    imag,label =batch
    ShowImage(imag)
    if(i>10):
        break

end = time.time()
print(end - start)
#output 7.922324180603027
```

commented code:

```
import torch 
import torchvision
from torchvision import transforms
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader

import time
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def ShowImage(imag):      
    temp=imag.view(3,96,96)
    temp=temp.cpu()
    temp =transforms.functional.to_pil_image(temp)
    plt.imshow(temp)
    plt.show()

path =  '/home/Machine Learning/Datasets'  
start = time.time()

# ToTensor = transforms.Compose([transforms.ToTensor()])
# train_data= torchvision.datasets.STL10(path ,
#                                        split='train'
#                                      ,transform=ToTensor) 
# test_data= torchvision.datasets.STL10(path ,
#                                        split='test'
#                                      ,transform=ToTensor) 
# dataloader_train = DataLoader(train_data,batch_size=1,shuffle=True)
for i,batch in enumerate(dataloader_train):
    imag,label =batch
    ShowImage(imag)
    if(i>10):
        break

end = time.time()
print(end - start)
#output 0.6654326915740967
```

Comment: Welcome to Spyder. Top level variables will be stored in a shared namespace so you need only load the file once and its name and data will be accessible in subsequent runs.

Comment: Note that this won't work outside of Spyder, I'm not aware of any way of doing this outside of the IDE. I would write in an answer if I could give you the defined behaviour but it's not so clear to me exactly what goes on. The gist is correct though.

Comment: Side note, if you redefine a builtin in the iPython console, that change will also persist. So if you do something like `max = 2` then `max` will be shadowed for every script you run because of the shared namespace until you restart the kernel